FAQ needs correction

What kind of questions should I ask here?
bitcoin - Stack Exchange is for people who like playing board games, designing board games or modifying the rules of existing board games.. 

I don't think this is correct...

This has been repaired to use the site's description.

Bitcoin - Stack Exchange is for Bitcoin crypto-currency enthusiasts.

